# $scope.$watch doesn't fire when I update from a directive

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the following code snippets:

**HTML:**

```
    <div data-filedrop data-ng-model="file"></div>
```

**Controller:**

```
    $scope.$watch('file', function(newVal) {
        if (newVal) {
            alert("File",newVal);
        }, false);
    }
```

**Directive:**

```
angular.module('app').directive('filedrop', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: './directives/filedrop.html',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=ngModel'
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            var dropzone = element[0];
            dropzone.ondragover = function () {
                this.className = 'hover';
                return false;
            };
            dropzone.ondragend = function () {
                this.className = '';
                return false;
            };
            dropzone.ondrop = function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                this.className = '';
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.ngModel = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
                });
                return false;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

The $watch function is never triggered when I update the $scope.

Any Ideas?? Might be an isolated scope issue? It used to work until yesterday... when I had to redo

> bower install && npm install

I can confirm:

- dropzone.ondrop is fired
- event.dataTransfer.files[0] does contain the file being dropped
- because of the bower install I also tried angular **2.1.14**, **2.1.15** and **2.1.16** (current) but none are working

Thanks!

Sander

Answer (score 1):

ngModel is a controller/provider, it's not a scope. It's not identical to using a scope like in a controller in any way whatsoever. You have to use ngModel.$setViewValue('some value') to manipulate the value. You also have to add the ngModel like this:

```
require: 'ngModel',    
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
    // do some stuff
    ngModel.$setViewValue(element.html()); // example
}
```

I found a good tutorial which describes this perfectly: http://suhairhassan.com/2013/05/01/getting-started-with-angularjs-directive.html#.U1jme-aSzQ4

Another option would of course be to just pass a scope variable like this:

Directive:

```
scope: {
    'someAttribute': '='
},

link: function(scope, element) {
    dropzone.ondrop = function(event) {
        scope.$apply(function() {     
            scope.someAttribute = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
        });
    }
}
```

Controller View:

```
<div filedrop some-attribute="mymodel"></div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.$watch('mymodel', function(newVal) {
   // yeah
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried this, but still didn't work :-( Stared at it for some more time and the problem was.... the HTML tag also had an "data-ng-if" in it.... changing that to "data-ng-show" solved it... WEIRD... That means directives that are removed from DOM is if condition is not met don't have "access" to the scope anymore??

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not modifying the value of scope.ngModel. Instead you are overwriting variable scope.ngModel so that it points to the different object, namely: event.dataTransfer.files[0]

Comment: Thanks! Tried this, but still didn't work :-( Stared at it for some more time and the problem was.... the HTML tag also had an "data-ng-if" in it.... changing that to "data-ng-show" solved it... WEIRD... That means directives that are removed from DOM is if condition is not met don't have "access" to the scope anymore??